# Add additional types to DTO

Tags: servicestack

I have a few classes on backend that I am not using in any DTOs but I would like to export to my DTO typescript file.

I tried adding them to `IncludeTypes` field but then only those types explicitly defined are exported.

Is there any way I can export all my DTO classes and specify some additional classes to export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack only exports Types in your Service Contract. The easiest way would be to add a `DummyTypes` Service holding the Types you want to export, e.g:

```
public class ExportTypes
{
    public MyType1 MyType1 { get; set; }
    public MyType2 MyType2 { get; set; }
}

public class ExportTypesService : Service 
{
    public object Any(ExportTypes request) => request;
}
```